# Where are my extra Spark tasks coming from

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark program that is training several ML algorithms. The code that generates the final stage of my job looks like this (in Kotlin):

```
val runConfigs = buildOptionsCrossProduct(opts)
log.info("Will run {} different configurations.", runConfigs.size)
val runConfigsRdd: JavaRDD<RunConfiguration> = sc.parallelize(runConfigs)

// Create an RDD mapping window size to the score for that window size.
val accuracyRdd = runConfigsRdd.mapToPair { runConfig: RunConfiguration ->
    runSingleOptionSet(runConfig, opts, trainingBroadcast, validBroadcast) }
accuracyRdd.saveAsTextFile(opts.output)
```

`runConfigs` is a list of 18 items. The log line right after the configs are generated shows:

> 17/02/06 19:23:20 INFO SparkJob: Will run 18 different configurations.

So I'd expect **at most** 18 tasks as there should be at most one task per stage per partition (at least that's my understanding). However, the History server reports **80** tasks most of which finish very quickly and, not surprisingly, produce no output:

[image]

There are in fact 80 output files generated with all but 18 of them being empty. My question is, what are the other 80 - 18 = 62 tasks in this stage doing and why did they get generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `SparkContext.parallelize` without providing `numSlices` argument so Spark is using `defaultParallelism` which is probably 80. In general `parallelize` tries to spread data uniformly between partitions but it doesn't remove empty ones so if you want to avoid executing empty task you should set `numSlices` to a number smaller or equal to `runConfigs.size`.